# No update from wcf Service to SignalR Web app

Tags: signalr, wcfserviceclient

Here is my wcfService code -

```
 public class SystemService : ISystemService
{
    private IHubContext hubContext;
    public SystemService()
    {
       hubContext = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<WebApplication1.MyHub1>();    
    } 

    public void SendMessage(string sender, string message)
    {
        hubContext.Clients.All.SendMessage(sender, message);  
    }
}
```

My web application with signalR hub is working fine.

```
    namespace WebApplication1
{
    [HubName("myHub1")]
    public class MyHub1 : Hub
    {
        public void SendMessage(string name, string message)
        {
            // Call the broadcastMessage method to update clients.
            Clients.All.broadcastMessage(name, message);

        }

    }
}
```

Only the messages from wcf client are not received.
No error messages in tracelog. If possible can anyone advice what I am missing here.
please ask if any other details needed.

Comment: I have researched already on stack overflow and other forums.. Didnt got anything  to resolve my issue(specific this issue)

Answer (score 0):

Changed the code to generate a proxy. And working now.

```
 public class SystemService : ISystemService
{
    private readonly IHubProxy proxy;
   // private IHubContext hubContext;
    public SystemService()
    {

       var con = new HubConnection("http://localhost:53098/");
        proxy = con.CreateHubProxy("myHub1");
        con.Start().Wait();
    } 

    public void SendMessage(string sender, string message)
    {
        proxy.Invoke("SendMessage", sender, message);
        //hubContext.Clients.All.SendMessage(sender, message);  
    }
}
```

But shocking, I was first trying with this method only but it didnt worked earlier.. So I tried with IhubContext as above in my question.